# Having trouble incorporating adding materials to current python code

Tags: python, materials

I previously had an issue that was solved by @scurest. He rewrote my code to make it much faster. I had another version of the code that applied different materials to each cylinder according to a value in an excel file. I have not figured out a way to incorporate this correctly. I get errors about my floats even though they worked previously. I also received this error:

```
TypeError: mathutils.Matrix.Diagonal(vector), invalid vector arg: sequence index 1 expected a number, found 'str' type,
```

Everytime I adjust something I get a new error. Please see the code below.

```
import math
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
import csv 
#opens csv file to be read and stores it as the variable f 
with open ('C:/Users/MacLab/Desktop/Modeling/Neuron 43 EM Post Analysis wo Labels.csv') as f:    
    #sorts through the data in f and makes a list of values from them
    readout=list(csv.reader(f))
    #print(readout) 

# Create a cylinder to use as a "template"
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
    vertices=32,
    radius=1,
    depth=1,
    enter_editmode=False,
)
cyl = bpy.context.object.data
cyl.name = 'tmp'
bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.context.object, do_unlink=True)

for ai, a in enumerate(readout):
    start_t = time.time()
    
    mesh = cyl.copy()
    mesh.name = a[0]
    radius = (a[3])
    depth = float(a[5])
    mesh.transform(Matrix.Diagonal([radius, radius, depth, 1]))

    #assign material to object
    #if the value in the coloumn referred is equal to 1, then get the dendrite material and add it to the active object
    if (a[18]) == 1:
        #get material
        mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Dendrite")
        #print('DR')
    #else if the value in the coloumn referred is equal to 2, then get the Terminal material and add it to the active object
    if (a[18]) == 3:
        #get material
        mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Both")
        #print('DR')
    if (a[18]) == 2:
        #get material
        mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Terminal")
        #print('PS')
    #in any other cases, get the Silhoutte material and add it to the active object
    else:
        #get material
        mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Silhouette")
        #print('NONE')
    
    # Copy the template cylinder and scale it to the right radius/depth.

    mesh.materials.append(mat)

    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(a[0], mesh)
    ob.location = (0, float(a[6]), 45000)
    ob.rotation_euler[0] = -math.pi / 2

    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)

    print("%d : took %.4f" % (ai, time.time() - start_t))

# Done with the template cylinder so remove it
bpy.data.meshes.remove(cyl)
```

I was able to use the code below and added zeros in the csv where the code was expecting values. I readded some floats and also changed two of my if statements to elif.

````
    import time
    import math
    import bpy
    from mathutils import Matrix
    import csv 
    #opens csv file to be read and stores it as the variable f 
    with open ('C:/Users/MacLab/Desktop/Modeling/Neuron 114 EM Post Analysis wo Labels.csv') as f:    
        #sorts through the data in f and makes a list of values from them
        readout=list(csv.reader(f))
        #print(readout) 
    
    # Create a cylinder to use as a "template"
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
        vertices=32,
        radius=1,
        depth=1,
        enter_editmode=False,
    )
    cyl = bpy.context.object.data
    cyl.name = 'tmp'
    bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.context.object, do_unlink=True)
    
    for ai, a in enumerate(readout):
        start_t = time.time()
        
        mesh = cyl.copy()
        mesh.name = a[0]
        radius = float(a[3])
        depth = float(a[5])
        mesh.transform(Matrix.Diagonal([radius, radius, depth, 1]))
    
        #assign material to object
        #if the value in the coloumn referred is equal to 1, then get the dendrite material and add it to the active object
        if float(a[21]) == 1:
            #get material
            mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Dendrite")
            print('DR')
        elif float(a[21]) == 3:
            #get material
            mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Both")
            print('BOTH')
        elif float(a[21]) == 2:
            #get material
            mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Terminal")
            print('PS')
            #in any other cases, get the Silhoutte material and add it to the active object
        else:
            #get material
            mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Silhouette")
            print('NONE')
        
        # Copy the template cylinder and scale it to the right radius/depth.
    
        mesh.materials.append(mat)
    
        ob = bpy.data.objects.new(a[0], mesh)
        ob.location = (0, float(a[6]), 25000)
        ob.rotation_euler[0] = -math.pi / 2
    
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)
    
        print("%d : took %.4f" % (ai, time.time() - start_t))
    
    # Done with the template cylinder so remove it
    bpy.data.meshes.remove(cyl)

```
````

Comment: `radius = float(a[3])`

Comment: and will run into similar hassles with `a[10]`  every item from csv will be a string unless converted eg `material_index = int(a[10]` ... `if material_index == 1`  or `if a[10] == "1"` or they'll never be true. ... it will twig, sooner or later,  to where the error messages become  pretty self explanatory.

Comment: in reference to radius = float(a[3])... the system is giving me this error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' ... it doesn't work when I remove float and has worked in the past with the float. I double checked that I am calling the correct column in the csv as well.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are saying in the other comment :/ would you be able to rephrase? i appreciate your help!!

Comment: `print(radius)` could it be the csv header line?

Comment: I fixed it!! Something weird with the csv expecting more values, so I just put in zeros. Might have also changed a couple of other things in the code. I'll edit with an update.
Thank you!